# SIP / VoIP account to Empathy in 14.04 (rakia or sofiasip)?

Tags: 14.04, empathy, voip, sip

How can I add SIP / VoIP capability in Empathy in 14.04?

Is "account-plugin-sip" package enough or do I have to install other packages like "telepathy-rakia" / "telepathy-sofiasip"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, installing telepathy-rakia was enough to be able to add a SIP account. I also installed account-plugin-sip afterwards but did not notice any difference (yet).

Comment: I had to install `account-plugin-sip` in addition to `telepathy-rakia` in order to have SIP in the "Online Accounts" of System Settings. Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, that is. (NOTE: I updated the [Gnome Wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Empathy/Protocols) as this should be the authoritative source for Empathy configuration.)